# Loop In Updating Table Data With Php And MySQL

Tags: php

I am developing an application that updates data in a table based on values selected from another table. I had searched the net,a nd tried to modify some samples to fit my needs, but still not working.

Below is some of my code:

```
$sync_2 = "
  select pin,ddt_1
  from purchases
  where (amount_to_repay-amount_repaid)>0
    and status like 'U%'
    and counter=1
";
$sync_2_res = mysqli_query($link, $sync_2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sync_2_res);
$data = mysqli_num_rows($sync_2_res);

$i;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $data; $i++) {
  $pin = $row['pin'];
  $ddt = $row['ddt_1'];
  $sql = "
    update deductions
    set amount = '$ddt_1'
    where pin = '$pin';
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}
```

Nothing is getting populated. Do I have to change the type of loop?.

Comment: your missing a `'` on `$row['ddt']` this would cause the script to give an error.

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors above, which are a lot more obvious when you indent you code sensibly.

Comment: I changed it. Still nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, which should do the whole operation in a single query:

```
$query = "
  UPDATE `deductions` `d`
  JOIN `purchases` `p` ON `p`.`pin` = `d`.`pin`
  SET `d`.`amount` = `p`.`ddt_1`
  WHERE
    (`p`.`amount_to_repay` - `p`.`amount_repaid`) > 0
    AND `p`.`status` LIKE 'U%'
    AND `p`.`counter` = 1
";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

AS YOU HAVE GIVEN there might be problem in your variable change $ddt_1 to $ddt in sql statement

```
 for($i=0;$i<=$data;$i++)

 {
 $pin=$row['pin'];
 $ddt=$row['ddt_1];
 $sql="update
  deductions
 set amount='$ddt'
 where pin='$pin';
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved PHP example

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ( "localhost", "root", "", "test" );
$sql  = "SELECT pin , ddt_1  from purchases WHERE  amount_to_repay-amount_repaid  >  0  AND  status like 'U%' AND counter = 1";
$sql2 = "update deductions  set amount = '%s'  where pin = '%s'; ";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = null ;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     $mysqli->query(sprintf ( $sql, $row ['pin'], $row ['ddt_1'] ));
}
```

**OLD POST**

Replace

```
 $ddt=$row['ddt_1];
```

With

```
 $ddt=$row['ddt_1'];
```

Replace

```
set amount='$ddt_1'
```

With

```
set amount='$ddt'
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

:)

Comment: yes because you did not close most of your strings .. i just added an improved PHP option for you

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that **mysqli_fetch_assoc()** only fetches one row, the row where the cursor is. Then it moves the cursor one row on. When the cursor gets to the end of the data **mysqli_fetch_assoc()** returns **NULL**.

So to iterate through a set of results people usually use a **while loop** as this is neatest:

```
$sync_2_res = mysqli_query($link, $sync_2);

if($sync_2_res == null) {
    echo "The sync2 query failed: " . mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Also its a good idea to check that the query worked and returned a result and not FALSE.

Next, I think there is a typo in the 2nd query: `$dtt_1` should be `$dtt`, and are you really sure that the `amount` field should be set to a string?

Anyway here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
$sync_2= "select pin,ddt_1 from purchases "
    . "where (amount_to_repay-amount_repaid)>0 "
    . "and status like 'U%' and counter=1";

$sync_2_res=mysqli_query($link,$sync_2);

// check the query worked
if(!$sync_2_res) {
    echo "The sync2 query failed: " . mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    // do something with $row
    $pin=$row['pin'];
    $ddt=$row['ddt_1'];
    // note change from $ddt_1 to $dtt
    $sql="update deductions set amount='$ddt' where pin='$pin';";

    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    // check query worked
   if(!$result) {
      echo "The 2nd query failed: " . mysqli_error($link);
   }
}
```